# Starting the car with dis-functioning fuel pump

Tags: fuel-system, mazda

I have mazda 6 diesel 2003 136hp and a problem with a fuel pump.
It seems that the suction control valve (SCV) needs to be replaced.
The problem is that the car will not start and I have to go to garage by myself.
Is there any way to make it running just for once?

I thought about pulling it over another car and try to start the engine from a gear, but I am not sure if that will help if the fuel pump is stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tow-starting won't work if you've not got any fuel going to the engine!

Where is the fuel pump? Is it somewhere that is fairly easy to remove, and just take the pump itself to be repaired rather than the whole car?

Otherwise I'm afriad you'll have to get a tow - most garages will offer such a service for a small fee.

Comment: thx Nick for a reply. I manage to tow-start the car but with many difficulties, basically the engine needed a bit of warmth and then SVC started to inject fuel. It was long towing before this happen. If SCV would be completely dead it would not work this way.